# NPM Publish Registry - 403 Forbidden - "You don't have permission to publish "..."

Tags: npm, registry, command-line-interface, publish

I've been trying to publish my package to the NPM Registry.
I get an error that I am not allowed to push my package to the registry.

`403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/qdb - You do not have permission to publish "qdb". Are you logged in as the correct user?`

I wonder why.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It looks like a package with that name was already published by someone else, so you'd need to use a different name in your package.json file and then `npm publish` again.

Else, you can look if you're trying to publish the same version that's already published.

Comment: i tried with another name, but still getting same error. could you please give another solution if possible?

Comment: this saved me alot of time

Comment: @Pavan, maybe you have published the same version that's already published?

Comment: @Pavan I am also getting same issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The name of the package was not unique

Comment: They should have said "already exist". By the way, thank you!

Comment: Woh, thank you a lot. I was struggling for a long time.This worked for me

Comment: This is helpful because if you don't update the version in `package.json` before you run `npm publish` you will receive a `403` error if that version has already been published.

Answer (score 78):

For me, I received this 403 error message when I had just created my NPM account, but not verified the email address on my account.  I found the verification request email from NPM, clicked the link, and magically was able to publish my first package.

Comment: THIS! THANKS! Wasted so much time on that.

Comment: Thanks! The npm server could provide a better error message in this case :)

Comment: Thanks, I did not check my mail, Now it is working

Comment: For the win! Thanks Henry

Answer (score 9):

Happens either because of a duplicate package name or because you never verified your email address.

Comment: in my case was I neved made it to verify my email address lol, so you were right

Answer (score 5):

Check if you are publishing the same version. I needed to update the version of the package and `npm publish` again. From the Forbidden error that I was getting it was not obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that you need to be logged-in.

Run
`npm login` to be able to publish packages.

Answer (score 4):

There Could be many reasons for that

1. Email not verified, so first verify your email with npmjs.com
2. Someone else is using that same package name, it needs to be unique. So
   choose a unique name.
   You can change the name under package.json file.
3. If you are republishing same package with changes you made , you need to change version , eg - 1.0.0 to 1.0.1. You can change the varsion name under package.json file as well.

Answer (score 4):

check your email registration and confirm verification 
finaly repeat publish your package 
and i hope will work

Answer (score 3):

Also happens when an org name is already taken. Use the following URL:

https://www.npmjs.com/org/ORG_NAME_HERE

If you're getting a "404 Not Found" error, it means the name is free. Otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 3):

For me there was another project with the same name. I just change the name and npm publish then it works good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I just verified my email and error gone. Now I can publish my packages.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for this error is that your package name conflicts with an existing published package. NPM thinks that's the package you're trying to publish, and obviously, you don't have permission for it

Answer (score 1):

change name like that(also the version) 
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh9T9.png)

```
  "name": "npm-helloworld-testwwwyy-xx",
  "version": "1.0.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scope, the following conditions need to be met:

- Publishing to your user scope (example: @username/module)
- Publishing to an organization scope (example: @org/module)

@see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scope#publishing-public-scoped-packages-to-the-primary-npm-registry

Answer (score 1):

If you have already verified your NPM account, then the package name is already taken. You can use a scoped package name in this case. For example, change the package name in your `package.json` from 'some-package' to '@awesome-packages/some-package'

NPM will try to make a scoped package private by default (which is a paid feature) so below is the proper way to publish it:

```
$ npm publish --access=public
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was duplicate package name. Changing package name in `package.json` did the trick. There could be other two reasons:

1. Try `npm whoami` . If you do not have username displayed try `npm login`.
2. If you are trying to re-publish make sure you run `npm version major/minor/patch` as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had different email in my `npm config` than what my npm login is set up with.

So basically your `email` displayed via `npm config ls -l` should match the email specified in your npmjs.com account.

Answer (score 0):

if you publish with `NPM_TOKEN` be sure it has `publish` permission, not `read-only`

Answer (score 0):

Your package name was published before by another user

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the 403 Forbidden error appears because of either:

1. A duplicate package name already exists. In this case, we should select a different name.
2. Because you never verified your email address. In this case, verify the email address.

Answer (score -1):

This case of issue happen even though email is verified if you are Ubuntu user.

Add sudo cmd before npm login,

```
sudo npm login
```

Also use sudo while publish a module

```
sudo npm publish
```

Comment: Using `sudo` is definitely irrelevant.